# Docker - deliver the code to nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

How do I deliver the code of a containerized PHP application, whose image is based on busybox and contains only the code, between separate NGINX and PHP-FPM containers? I use the 3rd version of docker compose.

The Dockerfile of the image containing the code would be:

```
FROM busybox

#the app's code
RUN mkdir /app

VOLUME /app

#copy the app's code from the context into the image
COPY code /app
```

The docker-compose.yml file would be:

```
version: "3"
services:
  #the application's code
  #the volume is currently mounted from the host machine, but the code will be copied over into the image statically for production
  app:
   image: app
   volumes:
    - ../../code/cms/storage:/storage
   networks:
    - backend

  #webserver
  web:
   image: web
   depends_on:
    - app
    - php
   networks:
    - frontend
    - backend
   ports:
    - '8080:80'
    - '8081:443'

  #php
  php:
   image: php:7-fpm
   depends_on:
    - app
   networks:
    - backend

networks:
 cms-frontend:
   driver: "bridge"
 cms-backend:
   driver: "bridge"
```

The solutions I thought of, neither appropriate:

1) Use the volume from the app's container in the PHP and NGINX containers, but compose v3 doesn't allow it (the volumes_from directive). Can't use it.

2) Place the code in a named volume and connect it to the containers. Going this way I can't containerize the code. Can't use. (I'll also have to manually create this volume on every node in a swarm?)

3) Copy the code twice directly into images based on NGINX and PHP-FPM. Bad idea, I'll have to maintain them to be in concert.

Got stuck with this. Any other options? I might have misunderstood something, only beginning with Docker.

Comment: Okay well my first potential solution is to use Bind mounts for the development and copy the files (through the Dockerfile instructions) into the php image for production, also creating a volume exposing these files. Then I'm going to share this volume with the nginx container via docker-compose.yml using named volumes. Not sure if it's going to work out, but at least the docs confirm: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/#tips-for-using-bind-mounts-or-volumes

Comment: It works? I'm in a same as you, how to share the code?

Comment: @RafaelQm I got away from php and not sure how it'd work. But before that I had been playing with mounting code to the nginx container. To think of it, you probably only need the front controller in there, so you can try creating an empty index.php file there and playing with the nginx config.

Answer (score 3):

I too have been looking around to solve a similar issue and it seems Nginx + PHP-FPM is one of those exceptions when it is better to have both services running in one container for production. In development you can bind mount the project folder to both nginx and php containers. As per Bret Fisher's guide for good defaults for php: [php-docker-good-defaults](https://github.com/BretFisher/php-docker-good-defaults)

> So far, the Nginx + PHP-FPM combo is the only scenario that I recommend using multi-service containers for. It's a rather unique problem that doesn't always fit well in the model of "one container, one service". You could use two separate containers, one with nginx and one with php:fpm but I've tried that in production, and there are lots of downsides. A copy of the PHP code has to be in each container, they have to communicate over TCP which is much slower than Linux sockets used in a single container, and since you usually have a 1-to-1 relationship between them, the argument of individual service control is rather moot.

You can read more about setting up multiple service containers on the docker page here (it's also listed in the link above): [Docker Running Multiple Services in a Container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you have two options:

(1) Using Docker-compose : (this is for very simplistic development env)

You will have to build two separate container from nginx and php-fpm images. And then simply serve app folder from php-fpm on a web folder on nginx.

```
# The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dev.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    expose:
      - 9000
  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dev.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    links:
       - app:app
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

(2) Use a single Dockerfile to build everything in it.

- Start with some flavor of linux or php image
- install nginx
- Build your custom image
- And serve multi services docker container using supervisord

Comment: Why using docker-compose and mounting the code from the php-fpm container to the nginx container is for a simplistic dev env? I was going to go with this in production (although with stack instead of compose).

Comment: Please check carefully ... you need to find a way to serve the code from app container to web container (app container should be completely sealed). With the above code you are creating a volume which is accessible from host (which runs docker container). So anyone having access to your host can modify the code and then the application is affected inside the container as well. Also this mechanism is using docker container linking... and I think in order to futureproof your app ...you should be using docker networking ...and probably use the latest version of docker-compose syntax if possible.

Comment: I wasn't going to mount the code from the host if you meant this, it's for development only. The code will be copied over to the app image for production and exposed in read only mode to the web container. Although I'm not sure if this is possible and whether it requires deprecated links. Alternatively I could copy the code into both app and web images, but this is too much maintenance. How docker networking can help me to share the code between the containers?

Comment: well my set up is using a backend network through which nginx and php-fpm communicate. I didn't intentionally use any links. I read the docs and googled a lot and now it seems that I have only 2 options if I want these services in separate containers - mount the code from the php container or copy the code to both at the image building stage.